# Sublime Text 3: How does one tinker with the goto_definition command?

Tags: python, plugins, command, sublimetext3

This isn't a keyboard remap request. My current dilemma is an inability to edit the `goto_definition` command (bound to `F12` by default). If I could find the .py file for it, this would (hopefully) be a piece of cake.

The larger scope of my project requires me to modify the functionality of `goto_definition` to more closely resemble the equivalent function in CodeWright. I'm working in ST3, and reverting to ST2 isn't an option.

Let me more clearly elaborate on my hurdles:

- Locate the .py file which contains the information that `goto_definition` uses when it runs.
- Modify the nature of that command to be a little more flexible:

  - Essentially, there are a few methods, `EditElementHandleR`, `MSBsplineCurveCR`, `GetElementDescrP`, `GetModelRef`, and several others of similar nature.
  - There are "tags" appended to some of these, and if a method name is to have a tag, it will be one of the following four: `CR`, `CP`, `R`, and `P`.
  - There are also methods with these names, sans tags.
  - CodeWright's behavior in taking the programmer to the definition is to point to the equivalent method name, without the tags, ***even if the cursor was currently sitting on a method name with tags.***
  - Sublime cannot find the original method if I hit `F12` (recall: `goto_definition`) while the cursor is sitting in the "tagged" method name.

Here's the ideal situation: My cursor is sitting in a method named `EditElem|entHandleR` (`|` denotes cursor), and I hit `F12`. Sublime then takes me to the `EditElementHandle` definition.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, `goto_definition` isn't implemented in Python, it's part of Sublime's compiled executable (mostly written in C++), so it's not user-modifiable. However, there are several code intelligence plugins available, including [`SublimeCodeIntel`](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/SublimeCodeIntel) and [`Anaconda`](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Anaconda), that may be more amenable to your needs. Code intelligence isn't magic, it simply uses (in your case fuzzy) searches to match what's under the cursor to what's in the index of a language library. All you'd have to do is slightly alter the searching logic to check for the possible presence of one of your "tags", and just ignore it. You may even be able to write a wrapper for `goto_definition` that does this for you, and not go through the bother of learning a large codebase. Sublime's [API](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/api_reference.html) should help, as should looking closely at the source of `sublime.py` and `sublime_plugin.py`, as there are some undocumented functions.

Comment: "Unfortunately, goto_definition isn't implemented in Python" - this is not true - it is in `Packages/Default/symbol.py`

Comment: @KeithHall now why couldn't I find it when I searched 2 1/2 years ago? I guess I'll rewrite my answer. Thanks for the heads up!